# PostgreSQL: How can I create a temporary user and database for my unit tests?

Tags: c++, postgresql, unit-testing, libpq, libpqxx

I'm developing a C++ web application and I'm using PostgreSQL with `libpqxx`, on Ubuntu 16.04. The issue I'm having is that I need a portable (over Linux systems) way to run my unit tests.

What I have now is a class that controls database calls. I'd like to test how this class acts under my unit tests. For that, for every time I run a unit test, I'd like to:

1. Create a temp user
2. Create a dummy db
3. run my tests on it
4. delete the db
5. delete the user

Now doing the steps is fine with Google tests. I can create a fixture that will do them all reproducibly. BUT...

**How can I create a user with a password in one call (without being prompted for the password), so that I can create that user on the go and run my tests?**

The [manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/app-createuser.html) doesn't seem to provide a way to provide the password in an argument. I was hoping to do something like this:

```
system("createuser " + username + " -password abcdefg");
```

where `system()` runs a terminal command. Then I can connect to the DB server with that username and password to do my unit tests.

Another failed attempt for me was to pass an [sql query that would create the user](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-createuser.html) through the terminal:

```
system("psql -c \"CREATE ROLE joe PASSWORD 'aabbccdd';\"")
```

When I do this, I get the error:

```
psql: FATAL:  database "user" does not exist
```

where `user` is my unix username.

Remember that I cannot connect to the server with `libpqxx` because I don't have credentials yet (as the temporary user). Right? Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Is there any way to do what I'm planning here and make unit-tests runnable without user intervention?

Comment: Have you tried docker? With containers you don't need  to create temporary users or databases.

Comment: @Dan How could Docker help with this scenario? Could you elaborate? (I use Docker normally for build tests, not unit tests)

Comment: Well, don't know your architecture, but if you use Docker for tests, maybe you need something else. Anyway [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/14741) are some ways to run psql without password

Comment: @Dan Thanks. I'll be trying the methods in that link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with the `system("psql -c \"CREATE ROLE joe PASSWORD 'aabbccdd';\"")` call is that it doesn't specify a database to connect to which will then default to trying a database of the same name as the user logging in. Try adding `-d postgres` and see if it works.

Please note that this only creates the user, it doesn't create any database or give privileges to anything.